# LLVM backend for stack based machine

Tags: llvm, backend

Does anyone know any example of an open source LLVM backend for a stack based machine? I need this for education purposes.

Comment: http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~async/slides/03-09-pietrek.pdf

Comment: LLVM has an x86-32 and 64 backend.

Comment: I have one, but it's not complete. The major problem is fitting stack slot allocation into codegen.

https://github.com/Bigcheese/llvm/tree/aiobj/lib/Target/AIObj

I'm not making this an actually answer as the codegen isn't correct for multiple basic blocks, and the target is near esoteric. 

If you instead asked how one would do this I can say what I've learned and what other devs have recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM is a stack-based virtual machine. [VMKit](http://vmkit.llvm.org) was an open-source project of LLVM which implemented a JVM with a LLVM backend. The idea of VMKit was to create a toolkit for building virtual machines (or managed runtime environments) such as JVM, CLI/CLR, R's runtime etc. To find out more, see [Nicolas Geoffray's PhD thesis](http://vmkit.llvm.org/publications/thesis.html). While the project is retired, [the source code is still available](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/vmkit/trunk/).

Also, Microsoft have released [llilc](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc/) which is a LLVM JIT compiler for IL/MSIL/CIL (which could be argued is a stack machine). The JIT code [can be found here](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc/tree/master/lib/Jit).

Comment: VMKit and llilc are LLVM **frontends**, but OP asked about **backends**. It should compile LLVM IR to MSIL (for example), not MSIL to LLVM IR.

Comment: Well that is not how I interpret the question. Perhaps we should wait for the OP to update.

Comment: Actually, he was rather specific.  "Backend" and the question leaned towards taking LLVM IR and expressing Stack Machine code with it.

Comment: I see what you mean.