# How to write an LLVM backend for stack machine?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, llvm

When I'm trying to build an LLVM backend without defining `RegisterClass` instances in TableGen file, it throws the following error:

```
error:No 'RegisterClass' subclasses defined
```

How to define a stack machine target for LLVM (i.e. that doesn't use registers)?

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203323/llvm-backend-for-stack-based-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't do it. LLVM DAG is designed specifically for the register machines and is of a little value for a stack machine compilation. You'd need a custom backend instead.

One approach I was using for a similar problem (LLVM IR -> stack soft core on an FPGA) is following:

1) Out of SSA (reg2mem)

2) Build an intermediate tree representation (i.e., squash all the single-use register assignments into trees, if order allows). This is the main optimisation bottleneck, the less register assignments you leave, the better.

3) "Register allocation" for the remaining registers that all are represented as stack allocated variables now (hope your stack machine ISA allows it).

4) Translate the tree directly, without any instruction selection (you can do it on LLVM IR level instead with intrinsics and a custom instcombine pass).

EDIT: It's not easy to do this with the DAG based backend, it was never meant to be used this way.

The closest thing I can think about is to use the DAG backend to generate an intermediate register machine code, and then use a post-processing pass to re-order the instructions where possible and inject the stack allocated variables access otherwise. I.e., represent each of the stack machine instructions as a pseudo-instruction with 1 or 2 register arguments and 1 register result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my goal is to discover if it is possible without writing custom backend. So if you know **any** way to do that - write an update to your answer, please.

Comment: I'm still learning LLVM and it's not clear for me why DAG is bad for stack based machine. Docs say that SelectionDAG looks like this: `(fadd:f32 (fmul:f32 (fadd:f32 W, X), Y), Z)` - just like lisp ;) So it doesn't seem hard to translate that to stack-based machine code.

Comment: And for example X86 **is** stack-based, because as I understand if the arguments number is more than registers number, arguments are passed on stack. So, if my understanding is right, I should just avoid passing arguments to registers and pass the directly to stack. Now I created one register that I don't use, and backend isn't working (because it's incomplete yet), but I don't see a big problem.

Comment: And there's another option - registers can be mapped to memory. It's slower, but should work.

Comment: @KolesnichenkoDS Edges in the DAG are virtual registers. Stack machine requires a certain order in those edges (and may require some complicated spilling). Your option is just to spill everything, which is very inefficient. You can take a look at how I implemented LLVM IR to a stack machine conversion here: https://github.com/combinatorylogic/soc/blob/master/backends/small1/emit.hl - with a tree reordering and spilling.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with the admonition to just don't, you should take a look at the WebAssembly backend.

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/llvm/lib/Target/WebAssembly